# Regular expression for removing quotes from quoted numbers in a string

Tags: regex, t-sql, vbscript

Let's say I have a bunch of text like this (simplified example, but you get the idea):

```
INSERT stuff(a,b,c)     VALUES('1','a','1');
INSERT stuff(a,b,c)     VALUES('2','b','1');
INSERT stuff(a,b,c)     VALUES('3','c','2');
INSERT stuff(a,b,c)     VALUES('4','d','2');
INSERT stuff(a,b,c)     VALUES('5','e','3');
INSERT stuff(a,b,c)     VALUES('6','f','3');
```

I'm looking for a regular expression that removes the `''` from around every number but leaves the number alone.

Here's the catch.  **You can't count on the quoted numbers being in the same position every time**.

There might be cases where it actually looks like this:

```
INSERT stuff(a,b,c)     VALUES('6','3','f');
```

Something that would work with VBScript and the RegExp object would be nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what the syntax for VBScript objects are, but a global replacement with this will work:

```
Regex:   '([0-9]+)'
Replace: $1
```

Comment: That does it.  I didn't try that approach because I assumed that you'd need $1 for the first match, $2 for the second, etc and I couldn't see how to make that work with an arbitrary number of matches.  Obviously, I was mistaken :)